# Unable to retain the textbox value when the html page is completely loaded

Tags: javascript, html, client-side-scripting

I am trying to set the value of textbox in html page programmatically by javascript. The value is shown-up in textbox and disappears when the page is completely load. 
**Note : There is no server-side code written.**

HTML and Javascript code :

```js
function salutation(){
   document.getElementById('txt_salutation').value = 'Hi John';
}
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>This is website title</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="sample.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:powderblue;">
     <form id="form1" name="form1">
      Name:<br>
      <input id='txt_salutation' type='text'><br>
     </form>
     <button id='btn_submit' form = "form1" type="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="salutation()">Submit</button>
    </body>
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: Simply set the value of the input itself to "Hi John" and it's guaranteed to be there at load time no matter what. `<input value='Hi John'>`

Comment: @zer00ne this is not what Prem is intending to do. Value has to be set using button click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function salutation(){
     document.getElementById('txt_salutation').value = 'Hi John';
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>This is website title</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="sample.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:powderblue;">
     <form id="form1" name="form1">
      Name:<br>
      <input id='txt_salutation' type='text'><br>
     </form>
     <button id='btn_submit'  type="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="salutation()">Submit</button>
    </body>
```

i have removed attribute form=form1 from the button. to submit form make new button.

Comment: How removing the attribute form=form1 make this work?

Comment: if i hadn't removed it then it will try action attribute of the form tag. since you don't have define action attribute that's why its becoming blank page after clicking that button

Answer (score 1):

this will make the value shown-up in textbox and not disappear:

```js
    function salutation() {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('txt_salutation').value = 'Hi John';
        // send the data to server by ajax
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is website title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sample.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:powderblue;">
    <form id="form1" name="form1">
        Name:<br>
        <input id='txt_salutation' type='text'><br>
    </form>
    <button id='btn_submit' form = "form1" type="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="salutation()">Submit</button>
</body>
```

Comment: will it submit the form when its needed?

Comment: @Nihal,if you want to submit the form ,you have to send the data by ajax

Answer (score 0):

Following should be considered before reading further:

> `form` attribute is not supported in any IE, and only with Chrome 10 + and Firefox 4+. See this [HTML `<button>` form Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_form.asp)

When you `click` the button with type `submit`, following happens:

> The form will be submitted to the server and the browser will redirect away to the current address of the browser and append as query string parameters the values of the input fields.

Since there is no `action` set on form, browser redirects to same page.

And since it is redirection (not postback), the value you set by javascript is lost from input box during redirection.

If you click the **browser back** button, you will see the value `'Hi John'` set in the textbox.

If you are not sure of which browser will be used by users then, it is highly recommended to use the features that are supported by all browsers

So, nothing is wrong with your code.